# Issue running bash script at if statement

Tags: if-statement, applescript

I am just getting starting in AppleScript and am testing out an existing script to see if I can get it to run on my computer. The error I get is here:

Expected “,” or “]” but found unknown token.

and it highlights the ~ in my if statement:

```
path="/Library/Desktop Pictures/Wallpaper-Blue-3D-logolow-2846x1600.jpg"
    
    if [ -d ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/ ]
    then
            echo "Desktop Pictures directory already exists"
    else
            mkdir ~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/
    fi
```

What am I missing? Thanks!!

Comment: Assuming you literally just copied and pasted that **shell script** _code_ into **Script Editor** and tried to run it... Well... you cannot do that, as **Script Editor** is for **AppleScript** _code_ (and **JAX** _code_). There is of course the `do shell script` _command_ that can execute **shell script** _code_. So what is it you are actually trying to do? Run that **shell script** _code_ from within **AppleScript** using the `do shell script` _command_ or _transcode_ the **shell script** _code_ into **AppleScript** _code_ without the use of the `do shell script` _command_?

Comment: Also, `path="/Library/Desktop Pictures/Wallpaper-Blue-3D-logolow-2846x1600.jpg"` is defined but not used in the remaining _code_, so it has no purpose in the **shell script** _code_ shown, so what's supposed to be done with it?

Comment: To be more explicit: that's not AppleScript code, it's shell script code. The languages are quite different, so make sure you're working with examples and documentation for the right one.

Comment: @user3439894 thank you for this. I have learned SO much since i last posted. Thank you for this, i am all in on 'do shell script'. Appreciate it

Comment: @Gordon Davisson... yep– I see that now.. I wasn't understanding how the two could interact with each other, and following the incorrect examples. Thanks for your time this helped me clarify.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid giving full disk access to mkdir shell command, use better the System Events or the Finder:

```
try
    -- if the folder doesn't exist, then getting the alias will throw an error
    alias ("" & (path to library folder from user domain) & "Desktop Pictures")
on error
    -- Desktop Pictures of library of home doesn't exist, so create it
    tell application "System Events" -- or, tell to Finder
        make new folder at folder "Library" of home folder with properties {name:"Desktop Pictures"}
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: this is all very helpful. In fact just yesterday I read about unintentionally giving unnecessary access,etc by providing sudo and full paths in my script. I will look into the System Events documentation in AppleScript Dictionary. Thanks again for your time!